# PHP Bracket Array Within Key

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I currently have arrays with brackets within the arrays. i.e. `$variable[other[0]] = "something"`
I would like a small function where it would check through $variable and see if there are brackets. If there are brackets, then remove that section and add it as a multidimensional array. Is this possible? Thanks!
For example:

```
$variable = array(
    'test'      =>  "test",
    'what'      =>  "something else",
    'here[0]'   =>  "yeah",
    'here[1]'   =>  "weee"
);
print_r($variable);
```

This would output:

```
Array ( [test] => test [what] => something else [here[0]] => yeah [here[1]] => weee )
```

However, I would want it to run through a regex function and split up anything that had brackets and turn it into a multidimensional array.

This would be the intended output:
`Array ( [test] => test [what] => something else [here] => Array ( [0] => yeah [1] => weee ) )`

Comment: Possible to include your array structure?

Comment: Why did you tag this `regex`? Sure, you could use `preg_grep` to find and filter those keys before manually appending the subarrays. But a combination of [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) would be a simpler *workaround*.

Comment: Add valid example of output and what did you tried

Comment: This would be the intended output: `Array ( [test] => test [what] => something else [here] => Array ( [0] => yeah [1] => weee ) )`

Comment: @ashin999 cool, so what's your first attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) and [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) and

```
$variable = array(
    'test' => "test",
    'what' => "something else",
    'here[0]' => "yeah",
    'here[1]' => "weee"
);
$string = http_build_query($variable);
parse_str($string, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

http://3v4l.org/XLOHM

Comment: This did the trick! However, in case the field was empty, is there any way for it to not show as a zero, or is that just something that parse_str does?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $val) {
  preg_match_all('/\[([A-Za-z0-9 ]+?)\]/', $key, $out);
  if (!empty($out[0])) {
    $chopped = str_replace($out[0][0], "", $key);
    $innerkey = $out[1][0];
    $variable[$chopped][$innerkey] = $val;
    unset($variable[$key]);
  }
}
```